# Why does my Python dictionary iteration order change between runs?

Tags: python

I created a dictionary with some key-value pairs, but when I print them out using a for loop, the order seems to change sometimes.

For example:

```
my_dict = {"name": "Alice", "age": 30, "city": "New York"}

for key, value in my_dict.items():
  print(f"{key}: {value}")
```

Sometimes I see "name" printed first, other times it might be "age". I thought dictionaries stored things in order? Is this a bug, or am I misunderstanding something?